# Ember Unit Testing Components with bubble up action

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm attempting to write a unit test to ensure that properties are closed upon the closing of a modal.  However, I seem to be having issues with the action handling.  I keep getting the error message:
`Error: <q12-reports@component:add-team-modal::ember294> had no action handler for: hideModal`

Here is the modal.js component:

```
stopSearch: function(modal) {
  modal.send('hideModal');

  this.setProperties({
    searchTerm: ''
  });
},

actions: {
  modalCancelled: function(modal) {
    this.stopSearch(modal);
  },
  etc...
}
```

As you can see I'm bubbling up the `hideModal` action.  This is the unit test I'm attempting to write:

```
test('closing modal clears properties correctly', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);
  let component = this.subject();   
  let firstSearchTerm;

  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('searchTerm', 'test');
    firstSearchTerm = component.get('searchTerm');
    assert.ok(firstSearchTerm, 'test', 'set term properly');
    component.send('modalClosed', component);
  });

  assert.ok(firstSearchTerm, '', 'clears term properly');
})
```

Before people mention [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432512/how-can-i-unit-test-a-method-that-results-in-an-action), I have tried it below.

```
test('closing modal clears properties correctly', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);
  let component = this.subject();   

  let firstSearchTerm;
  let $component = this.append();

  let targetObject = {
    externalHideModal: function() {
      assert.ok(true, 'hide modal was called.');
      return true;
    }
  }

  component.set('hideModal', 'externalHideModal');
  component.set('targetObject', targetObject);

  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('searchTerm', 'test');
    firstSearchTerm = component.get('searchTerm');
    component.send('modalCancelled', component);
  });

  assert.ok(firstSearchTerm, '', 'clears term properly');
})
```

Integration test attempt (doesn't work).  The last assertion still reads 'test'.

```
test('Closing modal clears properties of modal', function(assert) {
   assert.expect(1);
   this.render(hbs`{{modal}}`);

   //open modal
   this.$('.search').click();

   this.setProperties({
     searchTerm: 'test'
   });

   this.set('searchTerm', 'test');

   assert.equal(this.get('searchTerm'), 'test', 'sets properly');

   // cancel out of modal
   this.$('.modal-footer button').eq(1).click();

   let searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm');

   assert.equal(searchTerm, '', 'clears results properly');
});
```

Comment: If anyone has any ideas about how to do this integration side, I could also experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert that your component sent an event you can add an event listener to your integration test context. This should also stop the unhandled event error from being thrown.

```
assert.expect(2);
...
this.on('hideModal', function() {
  assert.ok(true, 'hide modal event fired');
});
```

This is a bit harder to do with ember unit tests, so I would recommend using integration tests when testing component UI interactions.